# Invoke Method from MethodInfo with Custom Class as Parameter

Tags: c#, reflection, invoke, methodinfo

I have this scenario:
One custom class (Customer) with some properties, like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Handler { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

One custom class with the Method, like this:

```
public class CustomerMethods
{
    public static void Insert(Customer customer)
    {
        //Do Something...
    }
}
```

So, I will load a text file with some info, like class name, property name and property value.
But, the real problem is, how can I invoke the Insert Method from CustomerMethods class and pass Customer class as parameter after set the values of Handler and Name properties?

Oh, I almost forget, I am trying to avoid conditionals, because I have 100+ classes. /o\
Ty all, if you need more info, just tell me plz...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used only these strings to call static Insert method `WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1+CustomerMethods`     `WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1+Customer`      `Insert`

```
Type customerMethodsType = Type.GetType("WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1+CustomerMethods");
Type customerType = Type.GetType("WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1+Customer");
object customerObject =  Activator.CreateInstance(customerType);

customerType.GetProperty("Handler").SetValue(customerObject, 3, null);

customerMethodsType.InvokeMember(
    "Insert",
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod| BindingFlags.Static,
    null,
    null,
    new object[] { customerObject }
    );
```

Comment: Hi, in this case if i want to access the "Handler" property in customerObject and set the value to 3 before pass it as parameter, how coul i do that? thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
typeof(CustomerMethods).GetMethod(SomeName).Invoke(null, new Customer(...))
```

However, you should try to refactor your design and avoid this, if possible.

Comment: this way i would have to create a conditional for each class, because in runtime i can't get type using typeof, because i will have just "strings" from the text file (I am doing this for integration purposes, and to use the business tier that i already have).

Comment: @DiegoVieira: `typeof(AnyType).Assembly.GetType(SomeString)`

Comment: I think i get yor point, I will try this way. If it works, I will mark as answer. Thank you